# How do I globally set the text color in XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, color

With pdfLaTeX I typically used the following code to globally set the text color for all text in the document:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\color{red}
\section{A section heading}
some test text
\end{document}
```

Running the document through pdfLaTeX produces red text. Running this through XeLaTeX produces black text. Using package `color` instead of `xcolor` doesn't make a difference.

I'd like to globally set the text color for all text appearing in the document, i.e. the headings, the table of contents, all normal text, in figures, in equations, if possible in TikZ nodes, just everything.

Comment: Try placing `\color{red}` right after `\begin{document}`.

Comment: @Gonzalo Unfortunately, that doesn't work with Komascript. I've changed the example document accordingly.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here's a way to do it which will work whether you use XeLaTeX or not, and whether you use Komascript or not. It works by redefining the default color used by LaTeX.

```
\documentclass{report}
%\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\globalcolor}[1]{%
  \color{#1}\global\let\default@color\current@color
}
\makeatother

\AtBeginDocument{\globalcolor{red}}

\begin{document}

\section{A section heading}

some test text

\end{document}
```

Comment: This seems to be the only way working around a XeTeX bug that creates a problem with `white` text as illustrated here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28305/how-do-i-get-fontspec-to-work-with-text-color-white-in-xelatex So thanks a lot!

Comment: BTW, this will also set the default _drawing_ color for figures created using TikZ – which may or may not be desirable :-)

Comment: @ilpssun: you can get around this by using `\usepackage{etoolbox}` and then doing `\makeatletter\preto{\tikzpicture}{\color{black}\let\default@color\current@color}\makeatother`

Comment: Only LaTeX could be a document processing language where something as simple as setting foreground and background color requires importing packages and defining custom commands...

Answer (score 15):

Since you say you're using XeLaTeX, you can also define a colour in the font definition:

In order to change colours if you do this, you need to use `fontspec`'s `\addfontfeature` instead of the regular `\color` or `\textcolor` commands.  Alternatively, you can define a new font family for the other colour(s).

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Color=red]{Linux Libertine O}
\setsansfont[Color=red]{Linux Biolinum O}
\setmonofont[Color=red]{Inconsolata}
% If you will be changing colours a lot, it's best to define a new font family
% for each colour that you will use; if you're just changing a few times, then
% \addfontfeature is fine
\newfontfamily\blueroman[Color=blue]{Linux Libertine O} 

\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\texttt{Some mono text}

Some regular text.

{\addfontfeature{Color=blue} Some blue text without defining a new font family.}

{\blueroman Some blue text with a new font family command.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: then `\textcolor{blue}{blue}` won't work

Comment: @Herbert True.  You need to use `\addfontfeature` to do this, or make a new fontfamily.  I'll add this to my answer.

Comment: @Alan: I would only use the `Color` font feature if I really wanted all the colors specified in the document to be overwritten (e.g. to convert a document to black and white, pictures non-withstanding). Otherwise, redefining LaTeX's `\default@color` is much more natural, doesn't interfere with `\color` or `\textcolor` and works whatever the engine or the document class.

Comment: @Philippe Thanks for your comment and answer. Indeed, the above solution does not work for the text colour of `white` as illustrated by my other question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28305/how-do-i-get-fontspec-to-work-with-text-color-white-in-xelatex

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}     
\usepackage{xcolor}     
\AtBeginDocument{\color{red}}     
\addtokomafont{sectioning}{\color{red}}     
\begin{document}     
\section{A section heading}
     some test text     
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't work with Komascript. Section headings stay black. I've changed the minimum example accordingly.

Comment: sure, it does  ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Herbert! And please ignore my comment above, adding `\addtokomafont` fixes the problem, now it is working. I found that I can also get it working by putting one `\color` just before and one `\color` just after the `\begin{document}` (thanks to @Gonzalo)

Comment: While easy and elegant, it doesn't work for all the Komascript elements unless listed individually with `\addtokomafont`

Answer (score 3):

As Alan Munn suggested, since you're using XeLaTeX, you could use `fontspec`'s capabilities to set the color of the font. If you want all the text to be a given color, you can even set that in the default font features:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX,Color=red}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\setsansfont{Linux Biolinum O}
\setmonofont{Inconsolata}

\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\texttt{Some mono text}
Some regular text.
\end{document}
```

Comment: same here: color changes are not possible with color commands, onyl with another `\addfontfeatures{Color=blue}`

Comment: Also, this doesn't work with `white`