# How do I get fontspec to work with text color white in XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, color, fontspec

In a previous question ( [How do I globally set the text color in XeLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26549/how-do-i-globally-set-the-text-color-in-xelatex) ), I've asked how to globally set a text colour in XeLaTeX and got some excellent answers.

However, while the proposed mechanisms seem to work in most cases, they also seem to fail consistently for the colour `white`. I'm not sure if this is a bug or if I'm doing something wrong here, but please consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Color=white]{Linux Libertine O}
\setsansfont[Color=white]{Linux Biolinum O}
\setmonofont[Color=white]{Inconsolata}

\pagecolor{darkgray}

\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\texttt{Some mono text}
The text above is invisible as it is all black and not white.

{\addfontfeature{Color=yellow} Some yellow text showing up on the dark page.}
{\addfontfeature{Color=white} Some white text invisible on the dark page.}

\end{document}
```

The example follows @AlanMunn s suggestion on the other question. The result is:

[image: White text is black]

The white text is printed in black. Other colours (like yellow in the example) work well.

If I use @Herbert s suggestion of adding

```
\AtBeginDocument{\color{white}} 
\addtokomafont{sectioning}{\color{white}}
```

to the document, I keep stumbling over environments that are still black, like the captions of figures for example. In any case, the `\color` command seems to be stronger than the `fontspec` setting.

Any thoughts or solutions to this?

Comment: This looks like a bug (maybe in the driver?) It works with LuaLaTeX, so if that's an option for you, you could try that.  Alternatively, loading `xcolor` with the `[svgnames]` option and using `Snow` instead of `white` gives you a very close approximation.

Comment: Another alternative is to use the technique that Philippe Goutet in your previous question. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26549/how-do-i-globally-set-the-text-color-in-xelatex/26560#26560

Comment: @AlanMunn Thanks for pointing back to Philippe's answer. Indeed, that's the one that should get the credit here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full credit goes to Philippe Goutet who wrote the follwing answer here: [How do I globally set the text color in XeLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26549/how-do-i-globally-set-the-text-color-in-xelatex/26560#26560)

Thanks to Alan Munn for pointing this out.

---

Here's a way to do it which will work whether you use XeLaTeX or not, and whether you use Komascript or not. It works by redefining the default color used by LaTeX.

```
\documentclass{report}
%\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\globalcolor}[1]{%
  \color{#1}\global\let\default@color\current@color
}
\makeatother

\AtBeginDocument{\globalcolor{red}}

\begin{document}

\section{A section heading}

some test text

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just doing `\color{red}` before `\begin{document}` would have the same effect.

Answer (score 8):

It seems to be a bug in XeTeX, as

```
\font\x="Linux Libertine O:color=FFFFFF"
\x ABC\bye
```

prints ABC in black, while

```
\font\x="Linux Libertine O:color=FFFFFE"
\x ABC\bye
```

prints ABC in "almost white".

So the answer might be

```
\setmainfont[Color=FFFFFE]{Linux Libertine O}
```

This "explains" Alan's suggestion.

Comment: You could make it `FEFEFE` for even color distribution.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good workaround, but not really `white`.

Comment: @kongo09: sorry, but it seems that really white is not accepted by XeTeX.