# Beamer shadows are different in pdfLateX and XeLaTeX

Tags: beamer, xetex, shading

I am getting different results on the shadows beneath the boxes (title page and all others) depending on whether I compile with pfdLaTeX or XeLaTeX. When compiling with pdfLaTeX the shading works as expected, but when compiling with XeLaTeX there is no shading at all, just a solid black background.

My log file just gives me the following errors:

> ! Missing { inserted.  
>                      - l.40 \end{frame}
>                    ! Missing { inserted.  
>                      - l.40 \end{frame}
>
> Overfull \hbox (299.25987pt too wide) detected at line 40 [] ! Missing
>   } inserted.  
>                   }
>
> l.40 \end{frame}
>                    ! Missing } inserted.  
>                   } l.40 \end{frame}
>
> Package pgf Warning: Your graphic driver pgfsys-xetex.def does not
>   support fadings. This warning is given only once on input line 40.

I tried the suggestion given on [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29503/3731), with no results.

How should I go about fixing this? Here's my test MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
%\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\usepackage{ifxetex}

% LANGUAGE
\ifxetex
   \usepackage{fontspec}
   \usepackage{polyglossia}
   \setmainlanguage{spanish}
   \setotherlanguage{english}
   \usepackage{xunicode}
   \setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Gill Sans MT}
   \setmonofont[Mapping=tex-text,Scale=MatchLowercase]{Monaco}
   \setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Baskerville}
\else
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \def\spanishoptions{mexico}
    \usepackage[spanish]{babel}
    \addto\captionsspanish{%
      \renewcommand{\contentsname}%
      {Contenidos}}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
\fi


\title[Short title]{Unusually long version of some generic title}
\subtitle{Important info, though not worthy of title status}
\author{A. U. Thor.}
\date{YYYY-MM-DD}
\institute[Short Institute]{Long form of the institutional name}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:introduction}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{First slide}
  Good stuff!
\end{frame}

\section{Body}
\label{sec:body}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Can't jump to conclusions just yet!}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Which `beamer` version do you have?

Comment: @JosephWright: beamer 2011/09/12 development version 3.18 A class for typesetting presentations (rcs-revision 70f9d8411e54)

Comment: Try updating your `beamer` to the current release (3.22).

Comment: `tlmgr` kindly requested that I upgrade to TeXLive 2012. I guess I should finally get around to it. I'll tell you how it goes in a few hours.

Comment: You can just download `beamer` from CTAN, if you prefer.

Comment: I was due for an upgrade anyway and mactex was just sitting there on my desktop, waiting... Anyway, it worked! I upgraded to v3.20,  and the compilation ran without errors and produced the expected shadows. Thanks! Would you write this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a 'known issue' with v3.18, which is fixed in v3.19 and later versions. Updating `beamer` should fix the problem.