# Title Slide of Flip Beamer Theme

Tags: beamer, xetex, themes

I just came across the [Flip Beamer Theme](http://www.lepp.cornell.edu/~pt267/files/code/FlipBeamerTemplate.pdf).

It is a cool theme to use on Beamer presentations, however, I don't understand how one has to customise the title slide of the presentation. The slide title and author name in the sample presentation go very well with the theme, but how do I recreate that?

Do I have to do this in something like photoshop? Or can it be done in XeLaTeX as well?

Comment: In http://www.lepp.cornell.edu/~pt267/files/code/ you find the template that was used to produce that presentation; as long as your system has the fonts used (Gill Sans, Helvetica, augie, and others, possibly), you shoul be used to produce the title page processing the template with XeLaTeX.

Comment: No... He just includes two pdf files which contain the title and his name! he doesnt give any tex files to generate those two...

Comment: What exactly are you trying to "recreate"? In other words, do you want to use this theme, and change the title & author to those of your presentation, or do you want to use the fonts from the sample presentation in the link in a Beamer presentation with another theme?

Comment: I guess I would like to do both. Basically I need the font and variant information for the ligatures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, the title page contains several PDF files using different fonts:

- The basic font of the beamer theme is [Gill Sans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gill_Sans)
- The Text reading "This is a sample talk title" is set in [Trebuchet MS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trebuchet_MS)
- The author's name ("Flip Tanedo") is set in [Zapfino](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zapfino)
- The logo of Cornell University is set in [Palatino](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palatino)

Here is a quick and dirty hack, based on the sources (the pictures are replaced by the text set in the corresponding fonts):

```
%% BEAMER THEME FLIP 2012: Main tex file for compiling
%$ Compile this file. 
%%
%% Copyright 2012 by Flip Tanedo
%% This file may be distributed and/or modified
%%  1. under the LaTeX Project Public License and/or
%%  2. under the GNU Public License.
%% 
%% If you e-mail Flip (pt267@cornell.edu) to say that you
%% like this style file, then it would make him smile.

%% Please see notes.txt for comments on Beamer Theme Flip 2013
%% By default, this template is meant to be run with XeLaTeX (for fonts)
%% To run in PDFLaTeX, remove fontspec and any font commands

%% Discussion of Beamer vs XeLaTeX vs LuaLaTeX
%% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29497/xelatex-preventing-beamer-from-using-different-backgrounds



\documentclass[12 pt]{beamer}
\usetheme[
    bullet=circle,      % Other option: square
    bigpagenumber,      % circled page number on lower right
    topline=true,           % colored bar at the top of the frame 
    shadow=false,           % Shading for beamer blocks
    watermark=BG_lower, % png file for the watermark
    ]{Flip}


\newcommand{\titleimage}{title}         % Custom title 
\newcommand{\tanedo}{tanedolight}       % Custom author name
\newcommand{\CMSSMDM}{CMSSMDMlight.png} % light background plot


%%%%%%%%%%
% FONTS %
%%%%%%%%%%

%% Default font: lmodern, doesn't require fontspec % solves some default warnings
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}            
%\usepackage{sfmath}        % Sans Serif Math, off by default

%% Protects fonts from Beamer screwing with them
%% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10488/force-computer-modern-in-math-mode
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}


%% XeLaTeX fonts: (comment out if you don't use XeLaTeX)

%% For advanced fonts: access local OS X fonts
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}      
%% This template uses typical OS X and Adobe fonts
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}  % This seems to be important for mapping glyphs properly

\setmainfont{Gill Sans}         % Beamer ignores "main font" in favor of sans font
\setsansfont{Gill Sans}         % This is the font that beamer will use by default
% \setmainfont{Gill Sans Light}     % Prettier, but harder to read

\setbeamerfont{title}{family=\fontspec{Gill Sans}}


\newcommand{\handwriting}{\fontspec{augie}} % From Emerald City, free font
% \newcommand{\handwriting}{}   % If you prefer no special handwriting font or don't have augie

%% Gill Sans doesn't look very nice when boldfaced
%% This is a hack to use Helvetica instead
%% Usage: \textbf{\forbold some stuff}
\newcommand{\forbold}{\fontspec{Helvetica}}
% \newcommand{\forbold}{} % if you want no special boldface



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Usual LaTeX Packages %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}           % For Weinberg-esque letters
\usepackage{cancel}             % For "SUSY-breaking" symbol
\usepackage{slashed}            % for slashed characters in math mode
\usepackage{bbm}                % for \mathbbm{1} (unit matrix)
\usepackage{amsthm}             % For theorem environment
\usepackage{multirow}           % For multi row cells in table
\usepackage{arydshln}           % For dashed lines in arrays and tables
\usepackage{tikzfeynman}        % For Feynman diagrams
% \usepackage{subfig}           % for sub figures
% \usepackage{young}            % For Young Tableaux
% \usepackage{xspace}           % For spacing after commands
% \usepackage{wrapfig}          % for Text wrap around figures
% \usepackage{framed}


\graphicspath{{images/}}    % Put all images in this directory. Avoids clutter.


\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees}  % For mind map
% http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/computer-science-mindmap/


% SOME COMMANDS THAT I FIND HANDY
% \renewcommand{\tilde}{\widetilde} % dinky tildes look silly, dosn't work with fontspec
\newcommand{\comment}[1]{\textcolor{comment}{\footnotesize{#1}\normalsize}} % comment mild
\newcommand{\Comment}[1]{\textcolor{Comment}{\footnotesize{#1}\normalsize}} % comment bold
\newcommand{\COMMENT}[1]{\textcolor{COMMENT}{\footnotesize{#1}\normalsize}} % comment crazy bold
\newcommand{\Alert}[1]{\textcolor{Alert}{#1}} % louder alert
\newcommand{\ALERT}[1]{\textcolor{ALERT}{#1}} % loudest alert
%% "\alert" is already a beamer pre-defined



\author[Flip Tanedo\quad {pt267@cornell.edu}]{Flip Tanedo}
\title[Flip's Beamer Theme]{Flip's Beamer Theme}
\institute{Cornell University}
\date{\today}



\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Additional  settings %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%% To use external nodes; http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/beamer-arrows/
\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]


{ %% This is a total kludge for a fancy title page background
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar right}{\llap{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{BG_upper}}}
\begin{frame}[c]%{\phantom{title page}} 
% The \phantom{title page} is a kludge to get the red bar on top
% \titlepage
\begin{center}
    % \includegraphics[width=7cm]{WarpedPenguinsReturn}

    \begin{tikzpicture}%[show background grid] %% Use grid for positioning, then turn off
        \node[inner sep=0pt,above right] (title) 
            { \fontspec{Trebuchet MS}\bfseries THIS IS A SAMPLE TALK TITLE };
            %       { \includegraphics[width=7cm]{\titleimage} };
        % \node (title) at (1.5,1.5) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \quad

    % \includegraphics[width=7cm]{\titleimage} 

    \vspace{1em}
    \footnotesize\textcolor{gray}{Journal of Cool Beans
    \texttt{[arXiv:1234.5678]}}
    \vspace{.5em}

    %\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{\tanedo} \quad
      {\fontspec{Zapfino} Flip Tanedo} \quad
    % \includegraphics[height=1cm]{FlipSansSerif} \quad
    \includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{CUasym}\\
    % \footnotesize\textcolor{gray}{In collaboration with} Csaba Cs\'aki\textcolor{gray}{,} Yuval Grossman\textcolor{gray}{, and} Yuhsin Tsai\normalsize\\
        \footnotesize\textcolor{gray}{In collaboration with 
        D. Grayson, J. Todd, T. Drake, S. Brown, D. Wayne}\normalsize\\
    \textcolor{normal text.fg!50!Comment}{\textit{Gotham University}, \today}
    % \textcolor{Comment}{ \;($\pi$ day)}\\
    % \Comment{4 February 2011}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
}



\end{document}
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, it is not identical with the original title page. But it leads to an answer to your question: If you have the fonts and you put in some work, the title page can be set with XeLaTeX. No need for photoshop and friends.