# Trouble setting background color using Standalone's convert command

Tags: backgrounds, standalone, png

I'm creating PNGs directly from LaTeX using the `xelatex`, the `standalone` document class and the `convert` option of `standalone`.  I have ImageMagick installed, and it all works fine.  The only issue is that the PNGs it's creating have a transparent background instead of the default white.

```
\documentclass[multi={minipage}, border=5, convert={true}]{standalone}

\usepackage{standalone}
\standaloneconfig{convert={convertexe={convert}}}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{500bp}
Some text
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

I'm using the `empty` pagestyle to make sure that there is no whitespace at the bottom of the pages.  Does anyone know what could be causing the PNGs to be transparent?  What is the syntax to manually set the background color?

Comment: I think your `minipage` is missing an argument.  But it is odd: with `pdftoppm -png <file>.pdf outfile.png`, the background is not transparent!  One temporary workaround might be to use `\usepackage{xcolor}` and `\pagecolor{white}`.  But I realize that is not a good solution.

Comment: Edited code to include the missing argument.  Even using xcolor and setting the pagecolor manually, I'm still getting a transparent background.

Comment: Well, I tried changing the color to orange, just to experiment, and that worked fine.  It's only when the pagecolor is white that I have the transparency issue.

Comment: Really?  It comes through as white (or orange) for me if I use `\pagecolor` and `\xcolor`, and compiling with `pdflatex -shell-escape`.  How are you compiling?

Comment: Ah I should've mentioned, I'm using xelatex since I need to use the fontspec package.

Answer (score 1):

I hope someone can give a real solution, but 'white' seems to be a problem with `XeTeX`; I don't see the problem with `LuaTeX`.  You can do 'almost-white', however:

```
\documentclass[multi={minipage}, border=5, convert={true}]{standalone}                
\usepackage{standalone}  
\standaloneconfig{convert={convertexe={convert}}}  
\pagestyle{empty}  
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\usepackage{xcolor}  
\begin{document}%\pagecolor{white}     
\begin{minipage}{500bp}  
% \pagecolor[HTML]{FFFFFE}%   white = FFFFFF
\pagecolor[RGB]{255,255,254}% white = 255,255,255 
Some text  
\end{minipage}    
\end{document}
```

It looks like 'white' is a problem for `XeTeX`; see @egreg's answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28321/8528).