# How do I turn a whole document to have blue text?

Tags: color

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I globally set the text color in XeLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26549/how-do-i-globally-set-the-text-color-in-xelatex)

I would like to pass an option to the `xcolor` package, or do anything else that will result in all text in my document to be blue.

I know you can use `\PassOptionsToPackage{gray}{xcolor}` to turn all text into grayscale, but I couldn't find a way to do it with "blue scale".

Comment: The accepted answer to this question: [How do I globally set the text color in XeLaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26549/2693) provides a solution.  (It's independent of XeLaTeX.)

Comment: A simple `\color{blue}` after `\begin{document}` (maybe also in the preamble) should do it for the "normal" LaTeX compilers.

Comment: I am little bit confused about what exactly is it that you want.  Loading `xcolor` with the `gray` option is very different from using `\color{gray}` in the preamble. Do you want all the text in your document to have the same uniform shade of blue, or do you want to translate different colors in your document to different shades of blue?