# fontspec setmainfont working

Tags: fontspec, document-classes

Here is a minimal problem example

```
\ProvidesClass{cvMinimal}[2012/04/30 CV class]
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

\LoadClass{article}


%%%%%%%%%%
% Colors %
%%%%%%%%%%

\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{green}{HTML}{C2E15F}
\definecolor{gray}{HTML}{4D4D4D}

%%%%%%%%%
% Fonts %
%%%%%%%%%

\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text, Color=gray]{Helvetica Neue Light}

%%%%%%%%%%
% Header %
%%%%%%%%%%

\RequirePackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\newcommand{\header}[0]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \node[](name){\fontsize{24pt}{72pt}\selectfont\color{green}{My Name}};  %
    \end{tikzpicture}  
    }
```

produces a gray "My name" wheras I would expect to produce a green one. Commenting the line setmainfont solves the problem.

Can someone explain me what do I do wrong ? And how to get what I want without commenting the setmainfontline which is important in the rest of my document?

I know it is possible since it is achieved in the cv [here](https://github.com/afriggeri/CV).

Comment: What about `{\addfontfeature{green}My Name}`?

Comment: Some related discussion: [How do I globally set the text color in XeLaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26549).  When you specify the colour in the font definition you lose the ability to set it with normal means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I suggested in my comment, the 'manual' way would be to call `\addfontfeature` where you want it.  Another solution would be to use the `SizeFeatures` option for `fontspec`.  Both are illustrated below.  (I used Adobe's [Source Sans Pro](https://github.com/adobe/source-sans-pro) since I don't have Helvetica.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{green}{HTML}{C2E15F}
\definecolor{gray}{HTML}{4D4D4D}

%%%%%%%%%
% Fonts %
%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[ Mapping=tex-text,
  SizeFeatures={
   {Size={-24}, Color=gray},
   {Size={24-}, Color=green}}
 ]{Source Sans Pro}

%%%%%%%%%%
% Header %
%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\newcommand{\header}[0]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
         % \node[](name){%                       <-- manual solution
         %   \fontsize{24pt}{72pt}\selectfont%
         %   {\addfontfeatures{Color=green}{My Name}}};
         %
         \node[](name2){%                       <-- uses SizeFeatures
           \fontsize{24pt}{72pt}\selectfont {My Name2}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }

\begin{document}

\header


my name;

\fontsize{24pt}{72pt}\selectfont my name;

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

In my opinion it's better to define separate font families: one for the main text font, another one for the special items. Here's an example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{cvgreen}{HTML}{C2E15F} % give distinctive names to colors
\definecolor{cvgray}{HTML}{4D4D4D}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,Color=cvgray]{Helvetica Neue Light}
\newfontfamily{\greenHelv}[Ligatures=TeX,Color=cvgreen]{Helvetica Neue Light}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\newcommand{\header}[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \node[](name){\fontsize{24pt}{72pt}\greenHelv #1};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\header{My Name}

\bigskip

\noindent Some text following
\end{document}
```

[image]