# How can I make all the text in this overleaf template black?

Tags: color, overleaf, code

I have a query, I want all the text of this overleaf template to be black and I can't find the line of code that puts all the words in black when I put it. no line I put does anything.
any ideas?
thanks!

https://es.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-a-masters-slash-doctoral-thesis/mkzrzktcbzfl

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26549/how-do-i-globally-set-the-text-color-in-xelatex

Comment: `\AtBeginDocument{\colorlet{mdtRed}{black}\hypersetup{hidelinks}}` added to your preamble should do the trick.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: See Appendix A of the template. All the color you see are links.  Add to `\AtBeginDocument{ ` located before `\begin{document}` the line `\hypersetup{hidelinks}`