How to change the color of text in all a document?, including footnotes, figures captions, table captions,
How to change the color of all the text in a document?, including footnotes, captions, line separating text-footnotes.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\color{cyan}

This is a test\footnote{Try and observe the result.}.

\end{document} 


https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26549/how-do-i-globally-set-the-text-color-in-xelatex

Solved! Thank you, @Stephen

see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/730718/2388
